# Not able to connect "private organizational git repo" to Power BI

Tags: git, github, powerbi

I am trying to pull some data from git to do some analytics as how many PRs have been submitted in a month, PRs related to a particular release, etc. In order to do that, I have downloaded the *GitHub app* in Power BI web application.
When I am trying to connect Power BI to git, I am not able to connect to my private organizational repo instead I am getting option to connect to public URL - "https://github.com/...". Find the screenshot below:
[image]

Please assist.

Just an update to add more description : I am using **GitHub Enterprise Server** with custom git URL.

Comment: What happens when you do sign in to GitHub? The text does say "Sign in to GitHub to continue to GitHub for Power BI", so it seems like this is the first hop, no?

Comment: Is your actually in GitHub or just in a private GIT repo?

Comment: Does this difference make any difference as Git repos are hosted on GitHub cloud!!!

Comment: The usual sign up will not work in my case as all such authentication happened through Organizational authentication system like ping id or oracle id etc.

Comment: According to their forums, [this has been a long requested feature](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=1da45a2b-f39d-42b0-9b42-c864553131c4), I guess they haven't added it. You should probably check the forums to see if updated information is available.

Comment: Thanks @LasseV.Karlsen for this information. I really do not understand why MS roll out half-baked features into market. This is such a common use case which I think most of the mid-level and big organizations are working on within their own Enterprise Git Servers... :-(